# sum of reciprocal numbers of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion

Let $^nC_k:=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$
Please prove that,for all natural number $k≥2$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n＝k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{^nC_k}＝\frac{1}{k-1}$

I tried to prove by induction, but I cannot. I guess it is proved by using Tayler series for some function, but I cannot find the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is known as the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem#Summation_formula), and is one of the fundamental Binomial Identities.